# Lua C API: undefined reference errors in liblua.a

Tags: c, linker, lua

I'm trying to compile a simple example of C code that includes Lua(5.2) libraries. I'm using the following command:

> ```
> gcc graph.c -o graph -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -llua
> ```

And getting the following errors:

```
    /usr/local/lib/liblua.a(lobject.o): In function `luaO_arith':
    lobject.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `floor'
    lobject.c:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `pow'
    /usr/local/lib/liblua.a(lvm.o): In function `luaV_execute':
    lvm.c:(.text+0x24e9): undefined reference to `floor'
    lvm.c:(.text+0x25fe): undefined reference to `pow'
   ...
```

Looks like the math library is not linked, but not sure how to fix it... Any suggestions? I installed Lua following instructions from the Readme with make linux and install linux (have Ubuntu 12.04). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added -lm and -ldl and it compiled. Sorry for duplicate... thought it is something specific to the Lua library. Thank you.

Comment: @OlaM It's worth reading the error message before posting. If you had read it attentively, you would have quickly found out that this has nothing to do with Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: you just need to add `-lm` to the end of the line.

(The man pages for all the functions that require it will mention this.)